# Odd hyphen added at end of blog post

Tags: posts, title

I can't get rid of the hyphen in the title of this WordPress blog. The hyphen appears when the blog is posted on Facebook. The hyphen also appears in the browsers tab after the title.

I tried deleting the entire title, yet the hyphen remains!

If anyone has an idea how to get rid of this hyphen, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've removed the link to your blog to both prevent political discussions and to prevent the post from being flagged as spam.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a theme issue. I believe it's trying to pull the site title or site description and append it after the hyphen. You can also see this issue occur if you hover your browser tabs title or view source and view the title tag. To test this theory you can follow the below instructions:

1) Log into WordPress
 2) Use the left-hand navigation and click on `Settings`
 3) Add text to both the `Site Title` and `Tagline` fields
 4) Click the `Save Changes` button at the bottom of this page

Additionally, you can install [Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) to better manage these on a per page basis.

Comment: Yoast is already installed. So yeah, check the Yoast SEO settings :-)